# YouTube API Search by Tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, youtube-api

I'm trying to add videos to an existing ASP.NET MVC site, and I'd like to show videos from our YouTube channel.

I have added a tag to each video to indicate what page it should appear on. I had thought that I could search our channel by tag on each page to render the relevant video on that page.

I'm trying to exclusively use the API v3, but it seems I can't do this.

I can't use developer tags, because videos are uploaded by multiple users using the standard YouTube front end. This seems like basic functionality, so I'm assuming it's my inexperience with this API.

As an example, our YouTube channel is `ChillinWithCharlie`. During development, one video is tagged `20141213Cheneys`.

I can get all videos in our channel, but is there a way to query the v3 API to retrieve **just** this video?

I've seen one suggestion here that I retrieve all videos, and filter in code. This feels inefficient, so I'd rather not do this, but I can't even see where the tag is returned with all channel videos, that I could interrogate in code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just you. There seems to be no specific query parameter to search by tag with API v3.
I would recommend doing a search with your tag in the 'q' (search) parameter, then checking the results to see if the tag exists in the returned snippet->tags property to verify the exact video.

Note YouTube tags are only visible to the video's uploader.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.tags[]